# How to handle uppercase and lowercase characters when using UIKeyCommand

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeycommand

We are in the process of receiving and processing keyboard input.

Among my source code,

```
UIKeyCommand *menuKey = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 77]
                                                modifierFlags:0
                                                       action:@selector(menuKey:)];
```

There is this part.

However, if you process it like this, it will only react when it is an uppercase 'M', and it does not respond when it is a lowercase 'm'.

Is there a way to handle UIKeyCommand with all uppercase and lowercase characters?

Comment: check if this link can help you http://nshipster.com/uikeycommand/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you only look for `77` which is ASCII code for `M`. In order to allow `m`, you need to add `109` as well

Comment: UIKeyCommand *menuKeyUpperCase = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 77]
                                                         modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierShift
                                                                action:@selector(menuKey:)];              Should I add this? Is there no other way without adding?

Answer (score 1):

You can add command for both Upper case Character and lowercase character

Comment: UIKeyCommand *menuKeyUpperCase = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 77] modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierShift action:@selector(menuKey:)]; Should I add this? Is there no other way without adding?

Comment: I don't see any other option.